# fread, use malloc as buffer

Tags: c, malloc, cs50, fread

I would like to use a malloc variable as a buffer for my fread function in C.

I use `fseek` and `ftell` to determine the size of my input audio file "audioSize":

```
//Seek the end of the file and then ask for the position
fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END);
audioSize= ftell(input);
```

once my input file size determined I use `malloc` to allocate it in memory:

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
BYTE* audio = (BYTE*) malloc(audioSize);
```

I would like to use this new allocated memory as a buffer for my `fread` function but I wasn't able, every time I run my program nothing is written in memory. I'm not sure how far is my logic from the solution, if some one could point me in the right direction I'm very thankful.

```
fread(&audio, sizeof(BYTE), audioSize, input);
```

Comment: `&audio` should just be `audIo`

Comment: You're reading into the pointer, not the allocated memory that it points to.

Comment: Don't do this.  Instead of seeking to try to guess the size of the file (the file may change size just after you seek), just read the data and grow the buffer as needed.

Comment: If you're going to seek to the end of the file as a hack to determine its size, you need to `rewind()` back to the beginning in order to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add error checking - always.
- Use the *value* of the pointer to save data, not the address of the pointer [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899017/fread-use-malloc-as-buffer/68900162#comment121765573_68899017).

  ```
     // fread(&audio, sizeof(BYTE), audioSize, input);
     fread(audio, sizeof(BYTE), audioSize, input);
  ```
- Be sure to rewind before reading again. [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899017/fread-use-malloc-as-buffer/68900162#comment121766143_68899017)
- Read in binary

---

```
FILE *inpout = fopen(fileanme, "rb");
if (input == NULL) Handle_Error();
if (fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END)) Handle_Error();
long audioSize = ftell(input);
if (audioSize == -1 || (unsigned long) audioSize > SIZE_MAX) Handle_Error();

unint8_t* audio = malloc((size_t) audioSize);     
if (audio == NULL) Handle_Error();

rewind(input);
size_t size_read = fread(audio, sizeof *audio, (size_t) audioSize, input);
fclose(input);
if (size_read != (size_t) audioSize) Handle_Error();

.... // Use audio

free(audio);
```

Comment: @FatSumo The copied text file is full of gramatical and stylistic errors, any idea what that could be ? ;-)

Comment: I found my mistake ^^, thanks everybody. as specified above, I wasn't writing my output file as a binary file: FILE* output = fopen(argv[2], "wb"); now it's working perfectly :-)